# Report Builder 3.0 Cannot Connect to an HTTPS Hosted Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

So we have a 2012 R2 SSRS server (a couple actually). We go to disable HTTP access on the Report Manager and Web Service URL. Everything is dandy until we try to open Report Builder and connect to the report server at `https://server.domain.com/ReportServer`. Its a no-go. We re-enable http on just the Web Service URL and then can connect to `http://server.domain.com/ReportServer` via Report Builder.

Our friend Google does not seem to know the answer. Hoping someone smarter might? Error message below.

[image]

I can confirm the server is up, the URL is correct (the `https` URL), and I have permission. Simply changing the `https` to `http` will allow the connection.

I have also reviewed the report server logs and found nothing of interest as it relates to this issue.

EDIT: We are in native mode.

Comment: I did find an answer, yes. There is a registry setting SchUseStrongCrypto that needs to be set for .Net. I’ll post an answer soon (when I am at a computer again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out after finding a laptop that Report Builder worked on and comparing against my machine where it didn't work. Digging through the registry and with the help of Google I finally found the following fix. A quick update to the registry, a reboot, and everything is working.

I imagine this is occurring because Report Builder was built on an older version of .NET that doesn't look for TLS 1.2 by default. So the registry entry tells .NET to give TLS 1.2 a try (I am sure it is more technical that that...).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: You good sir are a prince among men. Thought to myself it had to be 2.0 old as it was and was going to give up till you said it worked against 4.0

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance!